# Why does this trigger lock up?

Tags: mysql, triggers, repeat

I am using the trigger shown below to automatically assign a random key to inserted rows, retrying the random generation if an existing row is found.  99.9% of the time this works exactly as expected.  However, every couple of weeks or so the trigger locks up, the `REPEAT` loop within it apparently becoming infinite; the query continues indefinitely, effectively locking up the application, and has to be `KILL`ed.

As far as I can see, there is nothing about the logic involved that makes it seem as if this should ever happen.  The keyspace involved is certainly nowhere near exhaustion and never will be.  What is going on?

The trigger:

```
DELIMITER //;
CREATE TRIGGER `mytable_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE `curr` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE `sel` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    IF NEW.`mykey` IS NULL THEN
        REPEAT
            SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 18446744073709551615) INTO `sel`;
            SELECT `id` INTO `curr` FROM `mytable` WHERE `mykey` = `sel` LIMIT 1;
        UNTIL `curr` IS NULL END REPEAT;
        SET NEW.`mykey` = `sel`;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: This code is not thread-safe. You better create unique index for `mykey` and perform a loop in an application code

Comment: @zerkms: No, it isn't, but that isn't relevant.  The application is single-threaded; only one thing will ever be trying to do this at a time.

Comment: yes, it is. There is no guarantee 2 concurrent threads run and generate the same random `sel` in the very same moment. Though indeed, if you don't need thread-safe solution - you shouldn't care

Comment: @zerkms: Right, I'm saying it's not relevant to my situation because there is no possibility of two threads ever running this code simultaneously, because there is no possibility of two threads, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is this line

```
SELECT `id` INTO `curr` FROM `mytable` WHERE `mykey` = `sel` LIMIT 1;
```

If no row matches `mykey = sel` then curr isn't assigned at all.
So curr will never be null if it's ever assigned anything else.

Replace with something like this (untested)

```
DELIMITER //;
CREATE TRIGGER `mytable_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE `count` INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE `sel` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    IF NEW.`mykey` IS NULL THEN
        REPEAT
            SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 18446744073709551615) INTO `sel`;
            SELECT count(1) INTO `count` FROM `mytable` WHERE `mykey` = `sel`;
        UNTIL `count` = 0 END REPEAT;
        SET NEW.`mykey` = `sel`;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  Yeah, I was trying to treat the `SELECT INTO` like I could a subselect (with a `NULL` resulting from no matches), but it turns out the semantics aren't analogous.  Well spotted.